# TCP connections and Tomcat

Tags: database, tomcat, tcp, connection

I need to configure Tomcat 5.5 to receive direct TCP connections (instead of receiving HTTP connections).

The idea is to receive TCP connections from a client and store the information in a database.

Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

Your question embodies a contradiction in terms. Tomcat is a servlet container; servlets speak HTTP. You could always open a ServerSocket inside a Servlet or a ServletContextListener, but then what do you actually need Tomcat for at all?

Comment: I have mounted a Tomcat server infrastructure and would like to know how to use Tomcat to receive TCP / UDP easily.

The idea is that several mobile device makes a TCP connection IP: PORT in Tomcat get those connections.

The choice of the servlet and the opening of a socket I have also contemplated, but I can not think how, since I do not know at what point habrir the socket.

I also read something about ServletContextListener but not very clear to me.

thanks

Comment: @sleiva112 Well you've just summed up the available alternatives, but you still haven't answered the question. Why do you think you need Tomcat in this solution at all? I'm not saying there mightn't be reasons, but you've been asked and you haven't given any.

Comment: @sleiva112 Well, tomcat doesn't really give you any help in this regard

Comment: I need a solution for Tomcat because the production server where I have to make the changes you have installed Tomcat and I can not install more software (although if I can configure and modify Tomcat).

Answer (score 0):

While I think EJP is right, Tomcat is indended to serve http connections, here is a basic approach with a listener:

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class ServerSocketListener implements ServletContextListener {

     private ServerSocket serverSocket;
     private final int PORT = 8081;

     @Override
     public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
            System.out.println("Starting server socket at port: " + PORT);
            try {
                 serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
                 while (true) {
                      Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                      System.out.println("Client connected from: "+client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
                      //handle connection ...
                 }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
         try {
             if(serverSocket!=null) {
                 System.out.println("Stopping server socket at port: " + PORT);
                 serverSocket.close();
             }
         } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
 }
```

In your web.xml add these lines:

```
<listener>
     <listener-class>test.ServerSocketListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Then take your mobile and hit: http://[Server-ip]:8081/ .

Comment: You mustn't run the accept loop in the callback or the context will never finish initializing. Start a separate thread.

Comment: OK. Thank you. That's the idea.

What do you think a combination ServletContextListener and Netty or MINA?

Another question: do you have experience in Netty and MINA? What is best in performance?